# non trivial representation of the identity in the symmetric group by different transpositions

Tags: group-theory

Can we write $1\in S_n$ as $1=t_1...t_m$ for transpositions $t_i=(a_i\;b_i)$ with $t_i \neq t_j$ for $i\neq j$?

Comment: Yes, $(11)(22)=id$.

Comment: I should have added $a_i\neq b_i$.

Comment: Nobody can for $n \le 3$, I can for $n \ge 4$. (I am not sure whether anyone else can.)

Comment: As a hint for $S_4$, note that $S_4$ has a normal subgroup of order $4$ and the product of its three nontrivial elements is the identity.

Comment: To add to @DerekHolt's comment, I also can for $n\ge 4$ - intuition for me was to consider reflections of a square that compose to the identity

Comment: What happens if we order all transpositions of $S_n$ in an arbitrary way. Can we always write $1=t_1 ... t_m$ non trivialy for $n\geq 4$ if $t_1 ... t_m$ have to agree with the order defined on all transpositions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try
$$(14)(34)(12)(13)(24)(23)$$