# representation of 1 in the symmetric group by transpositions given a fixed order

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups

We can write $1\in S_n$ non trivialy via different transpositions for $n\geq 4$. For example $1 = (1\;4)(3\;4)(1\;2)(1\;3)(2\;4)(2\;3)$. However if we fix an order of all transpositions such that transpositions in the representation of $1$ have to agree with that order, can we still always find a non trivial representation of $1$? And if no, for what orders can we not find it given $n$?

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3397727/non-trivial-representation-of-the-identity-in-the-symmetric-group-by-different-t) for useful comments on it.

Comment: Probably for large enough $n$. The number of elements, not necessarily distinct, that you can generate this way from some fixed ordering is asymptotically much larger than $n!/2$, so intuitively you should hit most elements of the alternating group, with one of them probably being the identity.

Comment: you can show that you hit every element like that for a fixed order

Comment: including the trivial representation is what i meant, so you always get $1$. however can you order you elements such that you avoid all non trivial representations of $1$?